# Complexity Solving recursion equation

Tags: computer-science

Does anyone knows how to solve this Complexity equation?.

```
T(n)=sqrt(n)T(sqrt(n))+nlogn
```

so i solved it.

this is the solution
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIcFn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recursive definition:

```
T(1) = c
T(n) = sqrt(n) * T(sqrt(n)) + nlogn
```

We can assume fractional results are rounded down to the nearest integer. We can list out some values and try to guess the pattern:

```
n    T(n)
-    ----
1     c
2     1*(c)        +   2*log(2)   =    c +    2
4     2*(c + 2)    +   4*log(4)   =   2c +   12
16    4*(2c + 12)  +  16*log(16)  =   8c +  112
256  16*(8c + 112) + 256*log(256) = 128c + 3840
...
```

So far, we can easily notice that the term with `c` has a coefficient that's equal to one half of `n`. A moment's reflection will lead to the conclusion that this observation holds generally. Our other terms are getting built up like this:

```
                                    2log2
 2(2log2)                         + 4log4
 4(2(2log2) + 4log4)              + 16log16
16(4(2(2log2) + 4log4) + 16log16) + 256log256
...
```

We can use laws of logarithms to combine these terms as follows:

```
log(2^2)
log(2^4) + log(2^8)
log(2^16) + log(2^32) + log(2^64)
log(2^256) + log(2^512) + log(2^1024) + log(2^2192)
...
```

Thus, the constant for the `k`th element is a sum of `k` terms where the smallest term inside the log is `2^(2^(2^(k-1)))` and each of the subsequent terms inside their logs is twice the previous one. We can use laws of logs further to help get a closed-form solution:

```
log(2^2)
log(2^4) + 2log(2^4)
log(2^16) + 2log(2^16) + 4log(16)
log(2^256) + 2log(2^256) + 4log(2^256) + 8log(2^256)
...
```

We find we can express the value of the `k`th term using the minimum value `log(2^(2^(2^(k-1))))` and counting occurrences: 1, 1+2, 1+2+4, ... These counts form a sequence with closed form 2^k - 1. Therefore, the value of the `k`th element is `(2^k - 1)log(2^(2^(2^(k-1))))`.

The relationship between `n` and `k` is as follows:

```
k     n
-    ---
1      2 = sqrt(2^(2^k))
2      4 = sqrt(2^(2^k))
3     16 = sqrt(2^(2^k))
4    256 = sqrt(2^(2^k))
...

So, `n = sqrt(2^(2^k))`. This means `n^2 = 2^(2^k)`, `2logn = 2^k` and finally `k = loglogn + 1`. Replacing in our formula for the constant given `k` yields:

(2^(loglogn + 1) - 1)log(2^(2^(2^((loglogn + 1)-1))))
(2logn - 1)log(2^(2^(2^(loglogn)))
(2logn - 1)log(2^n)
(2logn - 1)n
```

Therefore, the term not involving `c` is `n(2logn - 1)`. Altogether, we have:

```
T(1) = c
T(n) = n(c/2 + 2logn - 1)
```

We have recovered an exact closed-form expression for the function whose recurrence relation you gave. Doing that is not always as straightforward as it was for this example.